# getting Kuler themes with AJAX

Tags: ajax, api

Is there a way to request Kuler themes using AJAX, and then storing the themes in an array or something? I've got the API key and verified it's working. But I can't seem to get it working with AJAX... :\

```
$.ajax({
  url:"http://kuler-api.adobe.com/rss/search.cfm",
  data: {"searchQuery":"blue", "key":"Wh47EV3R7HEK3YI5"},
  success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr, txt, err) {
     //I always end up here... :\
     console.log("error text: " + txt);
     console.log("error message: " + err); //undefined
  }
});
```

The so-called [documentation](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/kulerdev/A.+Kuler+API+Documentation) is of no help whatsoever...

**edit:** I've also tried this:

```
$.get("http://kuler-api.adobe.com/rss/search.cfm", 
      {"searchQuery":"blue", "key":"Wh47EV3R7HEK3YI5"},
      function(data) {
         console.log(data);
      }
);
```

Comment: I wish I had time for a full response but it appears as though you should be requesting data using the GET method and you should expect an XML response.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried the `$.get()` as well. And I'm fully aware of the fact that I'm expecting XML. But for now I just want the call to work...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's jQuery you've got in your code sample, but when asking this sort of thing, it'd be good to explicitly say whose $() you're calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your browser doesn't allow **cross-domain-requests** with ajax. Google for this problem (cross domain requests ajax)

Basically you serve your content and this ajax/javascript from say *http://www.mydomain.com* but then the script tries to make a call to *http://kuler-api.adobe.com* which isn't allowed for security reasons.

I too tend to forget about this sometimes, thats why I didn't catch it immediately.

Solution is to setup a gateway-script on your server which does the request on your behalf and then returns the data as response to the ajax call. (be sure to make the script save, so it can't be misused as open proxy)